# How to generate random keys in C# and use them in JSEncrypt

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, public-key, jsencrypt

I have to do data encryption on client side using **public key** and decryption on server side using **private key** in an asymmetric way, but I was unable to get which way to generate keys in **C#** and use them in **JSEncrypt**. Any another algorithms is the for supporting my scenario?

Comment: JSencrypt is a JavaScript library. You cannot run it in C#, but you can certainly generate RSA keys in C# and import then in JSEncrypt. You only have to make sure that JSEncrypt understands the key format the C# supports (PKCS#1 vs. PKCS#8).

Comment: how to implement  encryption on client side with public key using  RSA algorithm and i know how too decrypt on server side and key generation.

Answer (score 0):

For who needs JSEncrypt to encrypt with private key I forked, modified and I'm maintaining it.

https://github.com/michaeldisaro/jsencrypt

Private key encryption works, and also interoperability with C#.

Keys can be generated by the demo page, or from any C# backend. The important thing is to generate PKCS#1 private key with a PKCS#8 public key.